# CSS Grid - how to size videos in my grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Working on a project with Free Code Camp and I can't figure out how to size my videos correctly to fit into the grid columns/rows. I also don't understand why there's a white space at the bottom of my page. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/andrewcauthorn/pen/aMYbJr

`

```
#image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 625px; 
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  color: white;
}

  .container {
    font-size:;
    width: 100%;
    background: ;
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
  } 

#all {
  border: solid #552583;
  color: #FDB927;
}

h1 {
  color: #FDB927;
  text-align: center
} 

.d1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;

}

.d1 iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- metadata elements -->
  </head>
  <title id="title">The Black Mamba: Win Over Anything</title>
  <main id="main">
    <h1>The Black Mamba: The Legacy </h1>
    <div id="img-div">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://game7network.com/wp-content/uploads/137_1atiba_jefferson_kobe_bryant_3.jpg" id="image" alt="blah blah blah">
                <figcaption id="img-caption">
                  I am Kobe
                </figcaption>   
        </figure>
    </div>
<a href="https://ftw.usatoday.com/2015/12/kobe-bryant-stats-record-most-games-20-years-most-missed-shots-81-points-stats-michael-jordan-lakers" target="_blank">What's up</a>
    <article id="tribute-info">

 <div class="container">
  <div class="d1" id="all">20 time all-star</div>
  <div class="d2" id="all"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lf4biDUfwug" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
  <div class="d3" id="all">3</div>
  <div class="d4" id="all">4</div>
  <div class="d5" id="all">5</div>
</div>

    </article>              

  </main>
    <!-- page contents -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Also, you are missing the open tag dor `<body>`

Comment: Titles are normally put in `<head>`, so I suggest you move your `<title>` tag to inside of `<head>`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the whitespace, you just need to remove the default margin the browser adds to your body tag. You can do this by adding this into your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

To fix the resizing of the video, you want to replace your current `<iframe>` height and width values to be 100% of it's parent.

```
<iframe width='100%' height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lf4biDUfwug" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: He needs to change the height and width on the Youtube Iframe to 100% of the parent: `width="100%" height="100%"`. Add this to your answer  to solve the other question ;)

Comment: @SølveTornøe yeah i just figured that out; thanks though

Comment: Good answer @Rojo. Just to make it more explicit: the **only changes** you need on the `<iframe>` tag is the *width* and *height* to be relative (percentage) instead of fixed (pixels).
About the white space, you need to set the *margin* for `<body>` because of the default styling. More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro thanks! I'll make sure to explain better in other answers

Comment: Thank you, guys! This is my first time asking a question here and you all didn't disappoint. :)

Comment: @AndrewCauthorn If this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted. There is a check mark under the voting area of this answer, click it to accept this answer. This tells other people that your question is answered with a correct answer and don't add other random answers. It also helps me by giving reputation to me. :)